# How to search XML file using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, xml

I'm trying to write an app using World Weather Online services. The request from their website gives me a weather code telling the type of weather. This value is a number corresponding a description in a XML file which looks like this:

```
<condition>
    <code>119</code>
    <description>Cloudy</description>
    <day_icon>
      wsymbol_0003_white_cloud</day_icon>
    <night_icon>
      wsymbol_0004_black_low_cloud
    </night_icon>
    </condition>
  <condition>
    <code>116</code>
    <description>Partly Cloudy</description>
    <day_icon>wsymbol_0002_sunny_intervals</day_icon>
    <night_icon>wsymbol_0008_clear_sky_night</night_icon>
  </condition>
  <condition>
    <code>113</code>
    <description>Clear/Sunny</description>
    <day_icon>wsymbol_0001_sunny</day_icon>
    <night_icon>wsymbol_0008_clear_sky_night</night_icon>
  </condition>
```

Using this XML file gives me the advantage of making translations for other languages. What I need is to search for the code and get the description into a variable for later use.

How do I do this using jQuery?

/Carl

Answer (score 1):

**Working demo** http://jsfiddle.net/JtCrH/ or http://jsfiddle.net/usFtT/

API you are looking for is:

- `parseXMl` : https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/

Rest should fit your needs `:)`

**code**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var str = "<xml version='1.0'><condition><code>119</code><description>Cloudy</description><day_icon>wsymbol_0003_white_cloud</day_icon><night_icon>wsymbol_0004_black_low_cloud</night_icon></condition></xml>";
    var xmlDoc = $.parseXML(str);
    var $xml = $(xmlDoc);
    var $Name = $xml.find('code');
    var $Description = $xml.find('description');
    $('span').html($Name);
    $('span').append($Description);
});
```

Comment: Maybe I haven't explained myself properly. I have the <code> value, ex. 119, and I wan't to search for the <description> that fits the code.

Comment: Ah, okies, in thatcase see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542187/xml-to-javascript-array-with-jquery Change it into an array and then find the matching `code` and grab the `description` node. this should defo fit your cause. `:)`

Comment: Trying this:
var tmpCode, tmpDescription;
var weatherDescription = new Array();
 $.ajax({
    url: 'wwoConditionCodes.xml',
    type: 'GET', 
    dataType: 'xml',
    success: function(returnedXMLResponse){
        $('condition', returnedXMLResponse).each(function() {
             tmpCode = $('code', this).text();
             tmpDescription = $('description', this).text();
            
            weatherDescription[tmpCode] = tmpDescription;
        })
    }  
});

The array doesn't seem to work. How to display the description using for example weatherDescription[119] to display "Cloudy".

Comment: Sorry. I'm pretty new at using stackoverflow so I don't know how to format the text in comments.